# Should software allow saving a blank/empty document?

Tags: workflow

Certain types of software prevents saving a blank/empty document. Is there a reason for this?

Under what conditions is saving a blank document useful?

Comment: I see value in letting you save a blank document. As you mention, the first thing many users do is save the document in the correct place. Sometimes you may also want to create stubs for documents that will later need to be filled out by others or yourself. A small non-modal warning (e.g. 'Notice: this document is blank.' ) in the file save dialog would be welcome though.

Comment: I genuinely think that this is a good question. But it would only lead to discussions and opinions. There's an argument for both sides.

Comment: I vote to reopen. I like the question.

Answer (score 2):

Saving an empty document allows you to decide certain things (i.e. fileformat and filepath) now instead of later.

I create now a document, use the filechooser to select a location and fileformat and save the document. Then I start writing and only need to hit Ctrl-s later and do not need to do more.

The advantages are first, that I can decide to select these things now when I am thinking about them and not later when I was thinking about the content and I am not thinking about organizing my files anymore and second that I can save faster, i.e. click save and close the document.

Furthermore it may avoid data loss, when I can quickly save, e.g., when Windows decides it needs to reboot right now.
And last but not least, your editor can show the filename of the file you're editing right now when you already saved it, while it can only show "unnamed 1" or similar placeholders when you did not save the document, yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can save a blank document if a user has entered something (for example, a title / file name). If literally nothing was entered, then there’s no need to keep it.

The reason for that, I think, is to not generate empty documents, nobody will ever use. Otherwise you will need a functionality to delete them effectively (developers don't want to implement it).